# Ubuntu 18.04 connecting to wireless printer

Tags: drivers, wireless, 18.04

I need instructions to install a printer driver for a Canon MG6300 printer (a network printer) on an Ubuntu 18.04 operating system.

Comment: Access the CUPS server at http://localhost:631 -> `Administration` -> `Find New Printers`, if your wifi is up.

Comment: Have you tried Canon site? Is information missing there?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04 its a fun challenge! MY long winded Solution/work around!!!

Using Linux 18.04 and a wireless dongle. It should work for other versions as well.

Sometimes the WiFi just cant find your printer from/in Cups or Linux as there seems to be NO communications between the 2 spite your witless setup.

**aka-** Printer to PC via wireless dongle or other so too speak.

---

My thoughts.

I feel there is an absence of communications a the wireless...between localhost server,Apache,or CUPS localhost/631 and the wireless printer wirless network.

Much like trying too connect the internet thru your localhost "Apache server" (PC without internet only your local/pc server). "even though you may physically be connected to the internet", your sill using localhost.

.... anyway!!!!!

---

***(I'm not promoting PdaNet!!!!)*** I just own a copy and use it.

Download and **install PdaNet** on your cell phone. Try it out first or Purchase the app if the below works. Its worth its (1 - 2 S tar-bucks Mochas) cost in more ways than I use it for the printer work around.

I also use it for tethering (cell phone intenet to PC), even though my phone package allows it. my carrier just regulates/restrict data tethering too 5-gb/half per month if I use my PC. I hate restrictions/regulations. Thus PdaNet.... just saying!

PdaNet is for tethering your phones internet connection to your PC so your PC has internet...but it also works for printing connections (which PdaNet doesn't mention).... In my case it's a desperation easy (work around solution) and may work for you too.

**PdaNet** is for Win and Mac... but theres no auto installation setup for Linux. But **It WILL WORK on/for/with LINUX** you just need some manual settings "Easy setup Task! Minimal"

(see bottom notes) and read all of this as well.

I use PdaNet as a middle man (a hand off/relay client/router) between my printer and my Linux box.

**Try this (work around Trick)...it should work.**

After installing PdaNet on your cell phone...

**Cell phone Settings**

1. Turn on WiFi
2. Open  PdaNet -> choose **WiFi direct hot spot** activate it by using
   the checkbox. (no need for a data connection/internet on your cell..
   its local).

Done!

**Linux Settings**

Open/create (auto detect) a new WiFi connection in the settings.

- Once you see PdaNet Wireless connection in the list... click the WiFi
  gear settings icon beside it for the connection settings. You need
  the password from the settings tab....also shown on your cell phone/
  PdaNet.

(**In PdaNet "on your phone"**
at the top of the screen in your there will be a dialog pop up with the following settings:

- IP address n port number settings
- and password.
- Best to copy and note the SSID/Name as well. (Identity tab)...

This is the password you will/may need for both the Linux connection and printer.....
Hand Copy this password (if you need to) verify or replace the password in the Linux Wifi Gear setting unless it matches.

Apply the new setting.

You may need too Double click the new connection (or not) as to refresh/connect if it doesn't reconnect automatically.

Refresh/Re-Appear by turning off/on WiFi in Linux.
note: a type o in passwords will stop a connection dead in its tracks. Thus no connection.

**Printer Settings!**

(((((Some printers may need its **LAN Enabled**... as well)... After all, its on a "WiFi" **local area network**!)))))

Next---Printer setup WiFi/wireless connection

(in your printer) Go too your printer WiFi (Direct connect/wireless) options settings

Use your printer option too set up and scan for WiFi connections, Chose any listing with **PdaNet** in the listing.

- (Just note...You may be near another WiFi user and your printer picks
  up on their printer or network as well. Thus the password and name
  should match the one you want to set up on your Linux.)

Also,You may/may not need to enter the same (PdaNet) password noted above as to reach the connection. but you will most likely need the PW to connect the printer too your Cells PdaNet.

Now! Almost Done..
Delete any previous printer failed attempts (the printers) from Cups or your list of non connected printers.

Now (On your Linux PC web browsers)
type in the link below. Then select the Administrator tab:

- localhost/631

Re-scan/search for new printer... in cups  for printers. Use the local PC drivers for your printer.

Don't select the Network or other options.You want too choose a local connect-setings (you already connected if set correctly and working)..... and next-the drivers found on your Linux pc.
Use the drivers Stored/found on your Linux Box. Its Local. No need for The Network connection options such as IPP, HTTP,etc!

Simply select your brand from the list and choose your model when you choose your brand and go too the listings.

Try to find a new printer either in Linux or cups now!
try printing a test page.

Good luck!
Bob

BTW-
I have a wireless router as well the print will not work using my ASUS wire LAN RJ5/7,usb,wireless,etc... router.

If your pc and printer is blue tooth, then give that a try... you may not need PdaNet at all.

Installing new drivers? There's plenty of **"how too's"** on the web.

**Tethering PdaNet too PC in Linux via wireless?**

**Browser Not working?**

Copy the IP address and port number listed on PdaNet WiFi connection dialog box. port number as well.

**Usually
192.168.49.1    (all)Port 8000**  not other commons

Seems to only work with Firefox settings. chrome and others may not work.

**Linux 18..others?**

Go to ----

**In Linux-

Menu Gear > Network > Network Proxy** ...
The default usually shows "Automatic" which needs to be changed too **Manual**.

Click the **Network Gear** to change.
Change it from automatic to **Manual**.

Now Enter the IP address (for each field) you noted in PdaNet or above and enter it for http, https,socks and other except local host or Ignore. No need to fill in all the other stuff...just the basics.

All the ports should be the same.HTTPS port 8080 fails. socks as well if not set too 8000 or as PdaNet list.

**In FireFox**

Open Settings > General and/or search for
**Network settings**.
**change the settings to manual** as well
Enter the IP address mentioned earlier or the one from PdaNet if different (use PdaNet as it may change for your device), dont forget the port if asked.
Done!